# Raspberry Pi 4 Video Tearing Problem Playing on Chromium

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, chromium, chromium-embedded, raspberry-pi4

I have a web application that displays video. I'm running this on Raspberry Pi 4, OS Raspbian Buster.

My app plays a video with 1080p resolution on the screen using Chromium. The video works smoothly in the VLC player. When the video runs on Chromium, it tears the video.

When I examine the processor status during tearing, CPU usage goes up to %80 - %90, resulting in poor performance. I couldn't solve this problem by doing hardware acceleration in chrome settings (chrome://flags)

I've had this problem in Raspberry Pi 3 before. I solved this problem by installing a codec pack. However, in Raspberry Pi 4, this codec support seems to be incompatible. So there is no codec pack.

Is this a general problem? I've been looking for ways to solve this problem for quite a long time. Is there a method you know? I am open to any kind of support that has previously encountered such a problem or can provide information about the solution.

I look forward to your suggestions and ideas.

Thank you in advance for support.